# Error: No module: ngResource (Node/Express with Angular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, module

I am getting this error:

```
Error: No module: ngResource
```

I have included a script reference in my index.html file, like so (along with `ngRoute, ngSanitize, ngCookies`, and a directive called `angularjs.media.directive.js`):

```
<script src="/js/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

This is my server.js file, where I say "use" the static folder as `public` - I also set the `views` folder:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
});
```

My javascript files are located in the `/public/js` folder - am I loading the scripts correctly? Thanks in advance.

Order of scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/js/angularjs.media.directive.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/leader-board.js"></script>
```

`leader-board.js` is where the modules are injected.

Other errors that show up on load (possibly related):

```
TypeError: angular.$$minErr is not a function
    var $sanitizeMinErr = angular.$$minErr('$sanitize');
```

It looks like the media directive is being loaded twice - once by `socket.io` and once from `index.html`:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/js/angularjs.media.directive.js"
GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1400937921919 200 OK 1ms   
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8000/js/angularjs.media.directive.js" socket.io.js (line 1659)
```

**Per request:**

leader-board.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'angularjs.media.directives'
]);

app.directive('contestant', function(socket) {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.hide().fadeIn();
        };

    var controller = function($scope) {
            // Incoming
            socket.on('onContestantUpdated', function(data) {
                // Update if the same contestant
                if(data.id == $scope.contestant.id) {
                    $scope.contestant.display_name = data.display_name;
                    $scope.contestant.score = Number(data.score);
                }
            });

            // Outgoing
            $scope.updateContestant = function(contestant) {
                socket.emit('updateContestant', contestant);
            };

            $scope.deleteContestant = function(id) {
                $scope.ondelete({
                    id: id
                });
            };
        };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker,
        controller: controller,
        scope: {
            contestant: '=',
            ondelete: '&'
        }
    };
});

app.factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
        on: function(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if(callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/startup', {
      templateUrl: 'views/startup.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
    /*$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function($q, $location) {
      return {
        'responseError': function(response) {
          if(response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
          else {
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
        }
      };
    }]);*/
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, socket) {
    $scope.contestants = [];

  socket.emit('listContestants');

    // Incoming
  socket.on('onContestantsListed', function(data) {
    $scope.contestants.push.apply($scope.contestants, data);
  });

    socket.on('onContestantCreated', function(data) {
        $scope.contestants.push(data);
    });

    socket.on('onContestantDeleted', function(data) {
        $scope.handleDeleteContestant(data.id);
    });

    var _resetFormValidation = function() {
        $("input:first").focus();
        var $dirtyInputs = $("#ldrbd").find(".new input.ng-dirty")
                                      .removeClass("ng-dirty")
                                      .addClass("ng-pristine");
    };

    // Outgoing
    $scope.createContestant = function(display_name, score) {
        var contestant = {
            id: new Date().getTime(),
            display_name: display_name,
            score: Number(score)
        };

        $scope.contestants.push(contestant);
        socket.emit('createContestant', contestant);

        _resetFormValidation();
    };

    $scope.deleteContestant = function(id) {
        $scope.handleDeleteContestant(id);

        socket.emit('deleteContestant', {id: id});
    };

    $scope.handleDeleteContestant = function(id) {
        console.log('HANDLE DELETE CONTESTANT', id);

        var oldContestants = $scope.contestants,
        newContestants = [];

        angular.forEach(oldContestants, function(contestant) {
            if(contestant.id !== id) {
                newContestants.push(contestant);
            }
        });

        $scope.contestants = newContestants;
    }
});

// misc form validation stuff
$(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        // wait till angular is done populating the list

        // focus the first field
        $("input:first").focus();

        var $requiredInputs = $("#ldrbd").find("input[required]:not('.ng-dirty')");
        $requiredInputs.on("blur", function(){
            $(this)
                .removeClass("ng-pristine")
                .addClass("ng-dirty")
                .attr({
                    placeholder: "Required"
                });

        });
    }, 100);

});
```

Comment: @Gary Perry - know anything about node/express/angular?

Comment: Please paste code of how you have defined your application module with its dependencies.

Comment: @callmekatootie - sounds good - one sec

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure that AngularJS version 1.0.3 did not have a separate `ngRoute` module - that is, I don't think you have to include angular-route.js file. You seem to be mixing the AngularJS versions which may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @callmekatootie - what version should i be using? and i posted where the modules are injected

Comment: AngularJS 1.2.0 (onwards). You can use the latest stable version too. I think its 1.2.16

Comment: @callmekatootie so these? http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/ - do you see any other errors that might be causing the problem - im going to try using all cdns and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54344/discussion-between-callmekatootie-and-ewizard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, your AngularJS version is incorrect. `ngRoute` became a module of its own since 1.2.0.

You can use the latest version of AngularJS which is 1.2.16

Secondly, it seems like `angularjs.media.directives.js` file path is incorrect or the filename is incorrect. You might want to verify if that file really exists.

That should resolve the problem.